# How to extracts contents of a div tag containing a particular text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to BeautifulSoup and am looking to extract texts from a list inside a div tag. this is the code

```
<div class="contentBlurb">Description Synonyms 
    <ul class="definitionList">
       <li>Awaiting bone marrow transplant</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to extract the text "Awaiting bone marrow transplant".  This is the code which I use now which gives me an empty list:

```
for link in soup.findAll('div', text = re.compile('Description Synonyms ')):
    print link
```

Sorry for not adding this. I do have other divs by the same class name. I am interested in only the description synonyms.The other div is listed below

```
<div class="contentBlurb">Applicable To    
    <ul class="definitionList"> 
        <li>Patient waiting for organ availability</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `soup.find_all(class="contentBlurb").ul.li`

Comment: Thanks Dan , my issue is I have a couple of divs by the same class name. Sorry for not mentioning that in the question.

Comment: Will there always be that one `ul` inside that div, by class `definitionList`, or more of other class names?

Comment: i have added the other divs in the latest edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D`soup.find(text='...')` doesn't work if there's other text or tags inside that tag.

Try:

```
[i.find('ul', {'class': "definitionList"}).find('li').text
 for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': "contentBlurb"})
 if 'Description Synonyms' in str(i.text)][0]
```

Comment: thanks kevin how can I extract only the Description Synonyms and not the Applicable To  part without any regex ? any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Kevin's code works, it doesn't extract the Applicable To part

Comment: @dstudeba: Actually it's depends. My code only searches *the first match item* in the html code. So if the `Applicable To` part is before that  `Description Synonyms` part then my code doesn't work. *The safe way* is check if there's `Description Synonyms` in the class text or not. However edited.

Comment: I have made an edit to Kevin's approach and found the solution. Thanks Kevin. Here is the code I used.                                                                                       for i in soup.find_all('div', class_="contentBlurb"):
    if 'Description Synonyms' in i.text:
     print i.findAll('li')

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
    # coding: utf-8
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
html = """
<div class="contentBlurb">Description Synonyms
    <ul class="definitionList">
       <li>Awaiting bone marrow transplant</li>
    </ul>
</div>
 <div class="contentBlurb">Applicable To
 <ul class="definitionList">
 <li>Patient waiting for organ availability</li>
 </ul>
</div>
"""

souped = BeautifulSoup(html)
matching_divs = [div for div in souped.find_all(
    'div', {'class': 'contentBlurb'}) if 'Description Synonyms' in div.getText()]


li_elements = []
matching_uls = []

for mdiv in matching_divs:
    matching_uls.extend(mdiv.findAll('ul', {'class': 'definitionList'}))
for muls in matching_uls:
    li_elements.extend(muls.findAll('li'))

for li in li_elements:
    print(li.getText())
```

EDIT: Updated for matching particular div.

Comment: That will find all `<li>` tags on the page. Probably not what OP wants

Comment: @dan-klasson Oh yeah. I see. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Change it to the required string in the `if` clause. The below snippet will print if the tag's text has `Applicable To`, you can change it to your requirement

```
val = soup.find('div', {'class': 'contentBlurb'}).text
if "Description Synonyms" in val:
     print soup.find('div', {'class': 'contentBlurb'}).find('ul', {'class': 'definitionList'}).find('li').text
```

Comment: 1. OP wants the another one. 2. Did you see my answer...?

Comment: edited as per his requirement. And I did see your code, but by then i had already posted it. Sorry about it and thanks for pointing out the mistake anyway @KevinGuan!